# Java script field verification loop

Tags: javascript, loops, email-validation

I'm creating a form for moderators to add new users. The form can be expanded up to six rows. I've set js email verification but it only checks the first row, so I need to add a loop to check another rows' email fields if the moderator adds more than one row.

the HTML code is:

```
<td><input class="eml" name="email"></td>
```

and if more rows added, the field names would be:

```
<td><input class="eml" name="email"></td>
<td><input class="eml" name="email2"></td>
<td><input class="eml" name="email3"></td>
<td><input class="eml" name="email4"></td>
<td><input class="eml" name="email5"></td>
```

the js function i am using is:

```
function ValidateEmail()
{
var regexEmail = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
var email = document.getElementById("pls").elements.namedItem("email").value;
if (!(regexEmail.test(email))) {
  document.pls.email1.focus() ;
  //email.focus();
  alert("Please enter a valid email address");
  return false;
}
else {
  return true;
}
}
```

I know a way to do add a loop but the problem is I can't replace the 'email' name inside the `elements.namedItem("email")` with a variable

My questions are:

1. how can i have something like this:

`var email = document.getElementById("pls").elements.namedItem("email[i]").value;`

so i can repeat it within the loop to get next email field.

2. If you have any alternative ways, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: an easy way, but may not be available to you would be to use jquery, using an attribute starts with selector, you could select all elements that begin with [name^='email'] and loop through each element with the regex

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion but no jquery. I just want to add a loop to my code.

Comment: Why are you limiting the number of users that can be added? Make them unlimited, and use array style names `name=email[]`. Most server libraries will automatically create an array of parameters from this.

Comment: That regular expression won't allow a lot of [generic top-level domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#ICANN-era_generic_top-level_domains). It also won't allow valid addresses like `firstname+lastname@example.com`.

Comment: @robertklep so what do u suggest me to use?

Comment: This regexp will fail on any new TLD longer than four characters, such as `london`.

Comment: @PersianHero https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

appears you can also do attribute starts with selector using regular js, using querySelectorAll which returns a NodeList.

in the example of running code, the third email is empty when the function is ran so will focus and ask for a valid email

```js
function ValidateEmail() {
  var regexEmail = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

  var emailFields = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="email"]');

  for (var i = 0; i < emailFields.length; i++) {
    if (!regexEmail.test(emailFields[i].value)) {
      emailFields[i].focus();
      alert("Please enter a valid email address");
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

ValidateEmail();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> 
</head>
<body>
<td><input class="eml" name="email" value="validemail@test.com"></td><br>
<td><input class="eml" name="email2" value="validemail@test.com"></td><br>
<td><input class="eml" name="email3"></td><br>
<td><input class="eml" name="email4"></td><br>
<td><input class="eml" name="email5"></td>
</body>
</html>
```

if you are also using a form you could look into the "pattern" attribute on input tags, you can apply the regex directly to the fields

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, you can concatenate strings using the `+` operator.
So to get the string `'email1'`, you can just do `'email'+1`.

Therefore, inside your loop, you can have:

```
var email = document.getElementById("pls").elements.namedItem("email"+i).value;
```

If you insist on the first row having name `email` (instead of `email1`), you can do:

```
var iclean = (i === 1) ? '' : i;
var email = document.getElementById("pls").elements.namedItem("email"+iclean).value;
```

Comment: Thanks. how can I replace( "email"+i) with a variable. like: ($cnt)! – PersianHero just now   edit

Comment: @PersianHero `i` is a variable. If your loop iterates over `cnt` instead of `i`, you would use `("email"+cnt)`.

Comment: @PersianHero The other answer is cleaner for this specific case. (But I'm leaving this answer, as it may be useful to someone else in some instances.) You should also consider Barbar's comment about not limiting the number of inputs, or at least handing them as an array.